# Wrapping Enums using Boost-Python

Tags: python, boost, boost-python

I have problem wrapping an Enum for Python using Boost-Python.

Initially I intended to do something like the following in the *try-catch* (I've inserted my whole code below) statement:

```
main_namespace["Motion"] = enum_<TestClass::Motion>("Motion")
    .value("walk", TestClass::walk)
    .value("bike", TestClass::bike)
;
```

Everything was fine and compilation was done. At run time I got this error (which makes no sense to me):

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Motion'
```

Afterwards I decided to write a Python module using BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE in my code.
After initializing Python interpreter I wanted to use this module right away but didn't know how(?). The following is my whole code:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test)
{
    enum_<TestClass::Motion>("Motion")
        .value("walk", TestClass::walk)
        .value("bike", TestClass::bike)
    ;
}

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();

    try
    {    
        object pyMainModule = import("__main__");
        object main_namespace = pyMainModule.attr("__dict__");

        //What previously I intended to do
        //main_namespace["Motion"] = enum_<TestClass::Motion>("Motion")
        //  .value("walk", TestClass::walk)
        //  .value("bike", TestClass::bike)
        //;

        //I want to use my enum here
        //I need something like line below which makes me able to use the enum!

        exec("print 'hello world'", main_namespace, main_namespace);
    }
    catch(error_already_set const&)
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Anything useful to know about wrapping and using Enums in Python will be appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `AttributeError` is the result of trying to create a Python extension type without first setting scope.  The [`boost::python::enum_`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/v2/enum.html) constructor states:

> Constructs an `enum_` object holding a Python extension type derived from `int` which is named `name`. The `name`d attribute of the current scope is bound to the new extension type.

When embedding Python, to use a custom Python module, it is often easiest to use [`PyImport_AppendInittab`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/import.html#PyImport_AppendInittab), then import the module by name.

```
PyImport_AppendInittab("example", &initexample);
...
boost::python::object example = boost::python::import("example");
```

---

Here is a complete example showing two enumerations being exposed through Boost.Python.  One is included in a separate module (`example`) that is imported by `main`, and the other is exposed directly in `main`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

/// @brief Mockup class with a nested enum.
struct TestClass
{
  /// @brief Mocked enum.
  enum Motion
  {
    walk,
    bike 
  };

  // @brief Mocked enum.
  enum Color
  {
    red,
    blue
  };
};

/// @brief Python example module.
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::enum_<TestClass::Motion>("Motion")
    .value("walk", TestClass::walk)
    .value("bike", TestClass::bike)
    ;
}   

int main()
{
  PyImport_AppendInittab("example", &initexample); // Add example to built-in.
  Py_Initialize(); // Start interpreter.

  // Create the __main__ module.
  namespace python = boost::python;

  try
  {
    python::object main = python::import("__main__");
    python::object main_namespace = main.attr("__dict__");
    python::scope scope(main); // Force main scope

    // Expose TestClass::Color as Color
    python::enum_<TestClass::Color>("Color")
      .value("red", TestClass::red)
      .value("blue", TestClass::blue)
      ;

    // Print values of Color enumeration.
    python::exec(
      "print Color.values",
      main_namespace, main_namespace);

    // Get a handle to the Color enumeration.
    python::object color = main_namespace["Color"];
    python::object blue  = color.attr("blue");

    if (TestClass::blue == python::extract<TestClass::Color>(blue))
      std::cout << "blue enum values matched." << std::endl;

    // Import example module into main namespace.
    main_namespace["example"] = python::import("example");

    // Print the values of the Motion enumeration.
    python::exec(
      "print example.Motion.values",
      main_namespace, main_namespace);

    // Check if the Python enums match the C++ enum values.
    if (TestClass::bike == python::extract<TestClass::Motion>(
          main_namespace["example"].attr("Motion").attr("bike")))
      std::cout << "bike enum values matched." << std::endl;
  }
  catch (const python::error_already_set&)
  {
    PyErr_Print();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{0: __main__.Color.red, 1: __main__.Color.blue}
blue enum values matched.
{0: example.Motion.walk, 1: example.Motion.bike}
bike enum values matched.
```

Comment: Your demonstration fit the answer perfectly. Thanks for that. In the line you forced the scope was kind of trick to me. That solved my problem actually. I wanted to ask for a brief explanation about scopes in python. Actually I can not understand the difference between a scope and a namespace.

Comment: @NOVIN: [`scope`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/v2/scope.html#introduction) is a Boost.Python construct used to represent the namespace which will contain newly wrapped classes and functions.  Also, if you found the answer to be beneficial, you may consider [upvoting or accepting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.